# Is it possible to disable a CPU (not a core)?

Tags: cpu

Is it possible to disable a CPU, not a core? I want to do a test to verify if the performance could make a big difference or not.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides doing this in your BIOS grub has an option called `maxcpus`.

You can edit this option in when selecting your grub boot option by adding `maxcpus=1` to the parameters. Random grub picture:

[image]

Choose 'e' and you get to a command line where you can add options.

You can also create permanent boot option in grub by making a copy of your current boot option and add `maxcpus=1` to the boot parameters. You can name this 'Ubuntu, kernel 2.5.12-9-386 (1 cpu)' and have it amongst the other boot options like the picture shows.

You can verify running on 1 cpu by issuing:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo   | grep processor` this should show something like this:

```
processor    : 0
processor    : 1
```

And the 2nd line should disappear after booting with 1 CPU.

Comment: this question would also make a very mean practical joke! :D

Comment: What happens if you set maxcpus=0? :P

Comment: @Rinzwind I did exactly what you said, but the result seems weird, I got 12 processors info before adding "maxcpus=1" to the parameters when do grepping, but I only got 1 processor info after modification, it seems only one core in all 12 cores is activated.  Note: My computer has two six-core CPUs.

Comment: @crazy2be guessing: the 1st processor is called 0 so you end up using one? :D

Comment: @LeoYuan88 袁力皓 can you edit it the output of cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor before and after you boot with maxcpus=1?

Comment: @Rinzwind I could do that with the administrative priviledge, but does that mean anything ?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 13.10 workstation, this option works at "core" (called cpu in Linux) level and not processor level. I have a dual processor (hexacor each), and setting maxcpus=1 results in the kernel only managine one core instead of 12

Answer (score 7):

You can dynamically disable CPUs via `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/online`, for example to disable CPU 1, use:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

and to re-enable, use:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

Comment: This seems to disable an lcore, not a CPU. I have one of these directories for each logical core on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You can always unplug the CPU from its socket.  It's brute force, but you're guaranteed to get the test you want, and you don't have to worry if the kernel/BIOS/whatever switch is really doing what you hope it's doing.

My company has large installations of server farms in various locations around the world.  In our lab we'll sometimes remove CPUs from sockets for just such a test.

There's an interesting variation on this test that you can do with multi-CPU [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access) systems. On those types of motherboards you can remove all of the memory DIMMs that are controlled by one physical CPU.  The system will still boot just fine, and you can then run tests with your application pinned to various cores which will allow you to measure the affects of "local" or "remote" memory.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to unplug the CPU from its socket, could you show me how to do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Would like to see the performance of a multithreaded application along with number of cores? If that is the case, you can use taskset utility. I guess that you have a NUMA machine. You can install numactl utility and by using it you can find which cores corresponding to which CPU. For example, your machine has two quad-core CPUS (chips). By using taskset utility you can make cores of one CPU as a set and allocate these to your application. Then your application uses only one CPU/Chip (four cores). Please let me know if you need more information.